# TYPO3 9.5 - PLESK 17.8 - NGINX

Tags: symfony, nginx, typo3, plesk, typo3-9.x

have someone nginx and plesk without apache running?
Can someone share his nginx config for TYPO3 version 9,
because mine which I have used so far (for TYPO3 6-8) no longer works, every subpage redirects to the start page - but the url keeps the right one:

"domain.tld/mysubpage" redirects to the startpage "domain.tld" but the url in the browser bar "domain.tld/mysubpage" stays

TYPO3 site-config:
https://pastebin.com/2UW3yDeL

nginx config for plesk:
https://pastebin.com/Mr40S8na

Request:

```
[TYPO3_CONTEXT] => Development/Server
[USER] => ####
[HOME] => /var/www/vhosts/kunde
[HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=####; Typo3InstallTool=####; be_typo_user=####
[HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE] => Thu, 24 Jan 2019 13:38:02 GMT
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
[HTTP_DNT] => 1
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => ####
[HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
[HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
[HTTP_HOST] => domain.tld
[REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
[SERVER_NAME] => domain.tld
[SERVER_PORT] => 443
[SERVER_ADDR] => ####
[REMOTE_PORT] => ####
[REMOTE_ADDR] => ####
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.14.1
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[HTTPS] => on
[REQUEST_SCHEME] => https
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/2.0
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/vhosts/kunde/domain.tld
[DOCUMENT_URI] => /index.php
[REQUEST_URI] => /kontakt/news
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[CONTENT_LENGTH] => 
[CONTENT_TYPE] => 
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/vhosts/kunde/domain.tld/index.php
[PATH_INFO] => 
[FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
[PHP_SELF] => /index.php
[REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1548337126.09
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1548337126
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: Of course it was something tiny and my own stupidity!
In the site config was "http: //www.domain.tld - but the site was delivered via HTTPS." The problem was due to the fact ...

Now I've made it all away and it is only "www.domain.tld" in it - works.

Too bad that something is not in a log or so written - especially because actually a try catch block exist but just with a comment ...

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the lines from 163 to 172 with these. Hopefully it will work.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: thx but try_files doesen't work with plesk:
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213912945-After-switching-a-WordPress-website-to-FPM-served-by-nginx-it-fails-to-load-with-404-Not-Found-on-all-pages-except-start-page